# Formula to find sum of difference for specific categories

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have an Excel sheet with three columns: `category`, `baseline`, `current`:

```
category | base | current
apples   | 10   | 15
pears    | 8    | 8
apples   | 9    | 5
pears    | 10   | 15
apples   | 8    | 8
apples   | 9    | 10
```

Now, I need the difference if HIGHER current prices only for apples. In our example, the first, fourth and last line have bigger current prices but only the first and last line are apples, so I need the formula to return `6` (=15-10+10-9).

Is there any way to do it with Excel formula?

I found another answer that used `=SUMPRODUCT((c1:c3>b1:b3)*(c1:c3-b1:b3))` but that doesn't incorporate my category filter that also needs to be added.

Comment: Why not add a helper colum subtracting B from C and then just a simple SUMIFS?

Answer (score 2):

You should add a column to substract "current" to "base" (let's call it column D)
Then you should simply use a SUMIFS function to check that this column D is positive and that the category is equal to "apples".

The formula would look like this:

```
=SUMIFS(D2:D7,D2:D7,">0",A2:A7,"apples")
```

Comment: Sadly i have over 50 columns of data (months) so that probably doesnt work right?

Answer (score 0):

```
=SUM(QUERY(QUERY({A2:C}, 
 "select Col3-Col2 
  where Col1 = 'apples'"),
 "where Col1>0"))
```

[image: 0]

---

if you need to drag it across columns do this:

```
=SUM(QUERY(QUERY({$A$2:$Z}, 
 "select Col"&COLUMN()&"-Col2 
  where Col1 = 'apples'"),
 "where Col1>0"))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: Thanks for this great answer. Sadly I forgot to mention that my columns are over 50 months so the formula should be in row 1 but give results for every month. Your current formula with col3-col2 doesnt extend if move it to the other columns, meaning i need to manually change those column numbers. It's manageable but an automatic solution would be preferred. Is this possible you think?

Comment: I'm currently not behind my laptop, will share later, thanks!

Comment: Hi, here is a public link: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1m-b7oKGP9kxH8nfs_xoKMVKL2Z3EjzCrRkmeQsVuTCY/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: paste in F3 and drag down and to the right: `=SUM(QUERY(QUERY({$A$9:$Z}; 
 "select Col"&COLUMN()&"-Col"&COLUMN()-1&" 
  where Col3 = '"&$C3&"'");
 "where Col1>0"))` and also change +/- to reflect increase/decrease on every 2nd row